# Match and filter Column in CSV for Desired output

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a backup report in which I have multiple columns. I want to get only those clients who have never been successful in a particular group. If the same client with the same save set gets successful in other groups, then also I should get the client as failed for that particular group in which it is failing.

```
Get-Content E:\Report\Daily_Failed.csv |
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Select-Object -Unique * |
    Group-Object -Property 'Client Name','Save Set Name','Group' |
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 -and $_.Group.Status -eq 'Failed' } |
    Select-Object -Expand Group |
    Select-Object "Client Name", "Save Set Name", "status", "Group" |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation E:\Report\Final_Failed.csv
```

Input

```
Client Name,Save Set Name,Group,Status
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL, D_CWT_SQL_FULL,Failed
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:master,D_CWT_SQL_FULL, Success
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:model,D_CWT_SQL_FULL,Failed
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:msdb,D_CWT_SQL_FULL,Failed
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL,SQL_T-Log_15Mins,Success
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:master,SQL_T-Log_15Mins,Failed
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:model,SQL_T-Log_15Mins,Success
SQL01.abc.com,MSSQL:msdb,SQL_T-Log_15Mins,Success
5001.abc.com,G:\System,CWT_FS,Failed
5001.abc.com,G:\System,CWT_FS,Success
5001.abc.com,H:\System,CWT_FS,Failed
```

Desired Output

```
Client Name Save Set Name   Group            Status
SQL01.abc.com   MSSQL       D_CWT_SQL_FULL    Failed
SQL01.abc.com   MSSQL:model D_CWT_SQL_FULL    Failed
SQL01.abc.com   MSSQL:msdb  D_CWT_SQL_FULL    Failed
SQL01.abc.com   MSSQL:masterSQL_T-Log_15Mins  Failed
5001.abc.com    H:\System   CWT_FS            Failed
```

I want to output for all clients to a particular group which are failing.
  I tried filtering out the column with status and save set but in that, I didn't get the clients which are failed in one group and are successful in other groups.

Comment: What is your *current* output?  Also, a formatted input doesn't help anyone.  Post the raw CSV content.

Comment: Cuurent Output is 

"Client Name","Save Set Name","Status","Group"
5001.abc.com H:\System CWT_FS           Failed

Comment: Please DO NOT add the current output as comment, because it becomes unreadable. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57428727/edit) your question and paste it in there as formatted text.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is faulty, if the sum of Status=Success per group is zero you want to keep it.

```
Get-Content .\Daily_Failed.csv |
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Select-Object -Unique * |
    Group-Object -Property 'Client Name','Save Set Name','Group' | 
    Where-Object {0 -eq ($_.Group|Where-Object Status -eq 'Success').Count} |
    Select-Object -Expand Group |
    Select-Object "Client Name", "Save Set Name", "status", "Group"
```

Just without the export this yields:

```
Client Name   Save Set Name Status Group
-----------   ------------- ------ -----
SQL01.abc.com MSSQL         Failed D_CWT_SQL_FULL
SQL01.abc.com MSSQL:model   Failed D_CWT_SQL_FULL
SQL01.abc.com MSSQL:msdb    Failed D_CWT_SQL_FULL
SQL01.abc.com MSSQL:master  Failed SQL_T-Log_15Mins
5001.abc.com  H:\System     Failed CWT_FS
```